# Devise - Redirect automatically from root url if signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, redirect, devise, root

A user named Carly is not signed up and arrives at the index page. She signs up and gets automatically redirected to the main dashboard page. The user Carly which is now named CarlyCoolness123 closes her browser and goes to eat dinner. She gets on her PC again, but this time since she only remembers the actual index page called: coolness.com, and not coolness.com/index-dashboard. I want this user to be automatically redirect to the dashboard page if the user is signed in. That means that the user can't access the index page if the user is signed in. How do I do this? I've tried a couple of things, but since I assume that you people here have a lot better understanding with this than me I assume that my mistakes don't need to be included here.

Comment: Set the dashboard page as the root. If the user is not signed up, they are redirected to the signup page.

Comment: Nono, that is not what I am trying to do. I have 4 pages. Login page, sign up page, index page, dashboard page. A user logs in and when he visits the index page another time, the user will automatically be redirected to the dashboard page upon visiting the index page another time, somewhat like twitter when you are logged in and as well as facebook.

Comment: @MFCS what does "BUMP BUMP BUMP BUMP" mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This assumes that you have setup Devise correctly and you have a Dashboard controller that is responsible for rendering the dashboard view. In your app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb do this:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

...
end
```

Then in your config/routes.rb file add the following:

```
resources :dashboard

authenticated :user do
  root :to => "dashboard#index"
end

root :to => redirect("/users/sign_in")
```

If you have an index view for the dashboard, accessing the root of your app should automatically render it (if the user is signed in). If the user is not signed in, it will redirect to devise default sign_in view (if you haven't redefined it)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. This is my complete routes.rb file: 
Proxima::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
    resources :posts  
  root :to => 'posts#index'
  
  def checker
  authenticated :user do
  resources :users
  root :to => 'dashboard#index'
end
end

Comment: what is def checker? why do you have the 'resources :users' in the authenticated block? Have you defined the dashboard_controller and its before_filter?

Comment: actually it worked smoothly had to do some adjustmens, THank you soo much! :D

Comment: @MFCS  What adjustments did you have to make?  This is not working for me either.

Comment: In Rails 6 it will throw an error saying you have defined to "root" routes. The solution is to replace "root" in the authenticated block by "/".

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to use the below method, as it seems counterintuitive to me to have multiple root paths [read: "I was getting an error when I tried the other mentioned ways, so I tried something else."].

I think this works better and is actually what @MFCS was originally asking, since it doesn't make the root point somewhere else conditionally. Instead redirects to a different path when the signed in user visits the `root_path`:

config/routes.rb:

```
root to: 'welcome#index'
```

app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if user_signed_in?
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    end
  end
end
```

I prefer this, since the dashboard will still have the dashboard url show up in the browser (instead of the root url), although this may not be the preference of others, and also depends on your preferred user experience.

EDIT: I made a mistake in the code, referencing the DashboardController instead of the controller of the root resource.

Comment: this works, but seems to be a bad practice by moving one piece of the routing into the controller

Answer (score 1):

While this is an old post, I kinda ran into a similar problem and since I didn't use devise and use bcrypt instead, then this was the solution. I defined a `current_user` in my application controller and also `authorize`.

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user

  def authorize
    redirect_to 'home/index' unless current_user
  end
```

I then route all people to their secure dashboard and run before filter on all secure controllers like so `before_filter :authorize`, then if they fail, they are routed to the home page. Hope this helps someone in the future!